# How to change sheet name after reading an excel file without using openpyxl?

Tags: python

My problem is that I have an Excel file with multiple sheets inside, each sheet with its special name. Now, I'm trying to rename all the sheets through Python without using [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why is it that you don't want to use openpyxl?

Comment: @NathanRoberts it's the rule of the project

Comment: Please show the code you are using to read the Excel file

Comment: You could use pandas. Create a new excel file with the new sheet names. After everything is done delete the old file and rename the created file.

Comment: @Chris all I have at the moment is this:

trying = os.path.join("excel_workbooks", "remoteareavoting.xls")
all_worksheets = pd.read_excel(trying, sheet_name=None)
names = all_worksheets.keys()

it only reads the sheetname, can't figure out how to change it without openpyxl

Comment: The fact that you're using `pandas` is more important than what you are ***not*** using...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I see that the link you shared is by saving a new df to the excel file and saving it with the wanting name at the very first place, but I want to rename the existing sheets in my excel file

Comment: @mindy Isn't saving a new doc with new sheet names over top of the old file the same as a rename